# How to trigger native browser video download using JS

Tags: javascript, html, download

i want to write a button where user clicked will automatically download a video from a URL.

I have researched on someway, here is my implementation

```
 const startDownload = (
    url: string | undefined,
    filename = 'Tiktok_livestream.mp4',
  ) => {
    if (!download?.visible || clickedDownloadRef.current || !url) {
      console.log('here', download, clickedDownloadRef.current, url);
      return;
    }
    clickedDownloadRef.current = true;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => {
        console.log('finish downloading blob');
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(console.error);

    console.log('download');
  };
```

So the idea is we use fetch to download the data in to blob. Then save it.

The problem of this method is it doesnt have good UX for big files. Because the user only see the downloaded file widget of chrome after the fetch is done ( which take long time for big files). compared to a native video downloading where it will show when user start the download, and user can also see the progress.
So i wonder is there any otherway that will trigger the chrome widget right after user click the button, and continously show the progress

The widget im talking about is the native one usually automatically showed when chrome is downloading something
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the download progress natively, the server you are downloading from has to send the Content-Length header in its HTTP response. If you are downloading from a server that doesn't send this header, then your only recourse would be to put up your own relay server that your users send the file request to, and it responds by piping the video file from the true source and attaching the Content-Length header to the HTTP response it sends back to the user.